# Restrict command in powershell session but allow access to a cmdlet that calls it?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a bunch of PowerShell scripts that call out to external programs to perform certain actions (no choice about this). I'm trying to find a way to allow users to connect to a constrained remote session using delegation to run these scripts (and the external binaries) as a privileged account, WITHOUT the user being able to execute the binaries with the privileged account.

I've found that if I constrain the endpoint using NoLanguage and RestrictedRemoteSession, or using a startup script to remove access to those parts of the system that it breaks the scripts because they're no longer able to execute the binaries.

Is there any possibility of making this work, or will I have to rewrite my existing scripts as DLL cmdlets which could then make the calls to the external binaries (or write just a proxy command in a DLL to make the calls)?

Comment: did you figured out a way to solve this.

Comment: Pretty sure I just went with JEA in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Create scheduled tasks without a trigger, configure them to run as a privileged user, and have your restricted users start them from the Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for JEA or Just Enough Admin. It does exactly what you are trying to do with restricted endpoints.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/privatecloud/archive/2014/05/14/just-enough-administration-step-by-step.aspx

Start with the video. Jeffery Snover may give you the details needed to make your solution work as he explains step by step how JEA was built.